# Action ran severall times when clicking on overlapping features

Tags: qgis, python, actions

I have a layer of points and I associated a Python action to that layer which basically opens a url in the embedded QWebView.

This works well.

The issue I am facing is that if I zoom out and click on a region where several features are overlapping, the QWebView opens and reopens as many times as there are features stacked there.

Is there a way to prevent this? like:

- Stop previous action when a new one is launched

or

- Prevent the action to be ran for features that are not the first one visible

Comment: What would be the _"first one visible"_ ? If some objects are overlapping in a layer i'm not sure you can define any _"z-order"_ in the "objects stack" .... unless you have some useful additionnal information in your attribute table ?

Comment: You know, when you use the select tool and you click on a region where several features are overlapping, the one on the top - i.e. the "visible" one, or the one that is rendered on the top of the others - is the only one to be selected. I'd like to run the action the same way, only once for the feature that is "on the top".

Comment: I fear "on the top" has no meaning here ... in Python u can write maptools where, using the right geographical operator (like "contains"), u could eventually discriminate your overlapping features by clicking on a given area ... but it depends on the complexity of your layer ...

Comment: @snaileater I'm using the "Actions" environment to run the python script which means that I might not have the hand on what you mentioned. I believe that QGIS simply triggers the action for each elements that are where you click, and not only for the one "at the top" you know.
Did I misunderstood your comment? Let me know and thanks for your interest.

Comment: I see in [github code](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/release-2_18/src/app/qgsmaptoolfeatureaction.cpp#L109) that the actions are ran for all the features that intersect with a 2-searchRadiusMU-square centered on the click location. "searchRadiusMU" means search radius in map units, it is derived from "searchRadiusMM" which can be changed in `Settings > Options... > Map Tools > Identify > Search radius for identifying features and displaying map tips`.
The clicked coordinates are passed to the context: `$clickx` and `$clicky`, that might be a lead...

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, `$clickx` and `$clicky` were a good start. Here is the code that allows to perform an action only on the "top-most" feature: https://gist.github.com/ClemRz/e08d856ca93502b8fa3f16ad531110a5

Comment: This is surely not the most elegant/efficient way to do so. If someone has a better way please let me know!